# UX for when lastKnownLocation in Android is null

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

Working on some check-in functionality for an application, and trying to figure out the cleanest way to handle the lastKnowLocation being null. Currently, I attach a location listener and then fire off an asynctask which publishes an indeterminate progressdialog, alerting the user that I am searching for a the gps to gather their location; the doInBackground method is essentially just a busy wait loop, waiting on the location to not be null. As a disclaimer, I feel like this current implementation is bit "jenky" from a code standpoint, but provides the expected user experience. However, I am wondering if anybody could provide insight as to what would be a better way to handle this fairly common scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not for the progress dialog because if the GPS takes forever then so will your app, killing the UX. In the activity with the dialog why not have a global locationFound boolean, a lastLongitude and lastLatitude. The advantage of that being if the you use the GPS returned to open another activity and the user navigates backwards you can even implement a "See previous results" or whatever the terminology is for your app. Here's how i implemented a GPS location wait in an activity for a small app i did a while ago, excluding the code that doesn't matter for your question

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        TextView txt;
        Button btnGPS;
        Button btnSeeLast;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        String provider;
        boolean gotLoc;
        boolean hasLastLoc;
        double lastLat;
        double lastLon;
        LocationListener myLocationListener;


    @Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);  

}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .....
        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst);
        txt.setText("Waiting for GPS location");
        btnSeeLast = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSeeLast);
        btnSeeLast.setEnabled(false);
        hasLastLoc = false;
        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        gotLoc = false;
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
        provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        myLocationListener = new UpdatesReceiver();
        int t = 5000;
        int distance = 5;
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, t, distance, myLocationListener);
        checkGPS();
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null){
        gotLoc = true;
        updateWithNewLocation(location, true);
        }
      }

private void checkGPS(){
    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)){
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }   
}

public void btnSeeLastClick(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("latitude", String.valueOf(lastLat));
    intent.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(lastLon));
    intent.putExtra("prev", false);     
    startActivity(intent);

}


private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location, boolean prev){
    btnGPS.setEnabled(true);
    String latLongString;

    if (location != null){
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        //remember
        lastLat = lat;
    lastLon = lng;
    hasLastLoc = true;
    btnSeeLast.setEnabled(true);
        //end remember
        latLongString = "Latitude: " + lat + "\nLongitude: " + lng;
        txt.setText("");
        //txt.setText(latLongString);return;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AgentsList.class);
        intent.putExtra("latitude", String.valueOf(lat));
        intent.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(lng));

        if (prev){
            intent.putExtra("prev", true);              
        }
        else{
            intent.putExtra("prev", false);
        }
        startActivity(intent);

        }
    else{
        latLongString = "Failed to get a response from your GPS. Try again";
        txt.setText(latLongString);
        }



}

private class UpdatesReceiver implements LocationListener{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (gotLoc == false){
            gotLoc = true;
            updateWithNewLocation(location, false);


        }           

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
    // Update application if provider disabled.
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
    // Update application if provider enabled.
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
    // Update application if provider hardware status changed.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Takunda, thanks for your response. However, I am not quite sure as to what you are suggesting as to how to handle the lack of a known location, since you do not like the progress dialog.

Comment: As you will see in my code, there's a global boolean gotLoc. It is false when the activity is created and only set to true when the getLastKnownLocation returns something other than null, or when the location listener returns something. So that means when your app starts it can for example show text notifying the use that it is waiting for a location. When the locationListener gets an update that's when you launch the Activity that actually deals with the GPS values.

Comment: I do understand what you are doing, but the flow seems to be different than what I was after UX wise. I think I just poorly stated my question/left it too open ended.

Comment: Maybe so. What i was trying to demonstrate was that you should let GPS-wait happen asynchronously in the activity's background and the activity should notify the user of the wait. It's a nicer UX than waiting for a ProgressDialog. I'm putting the app i did on GitHub, will link it back here when i'm through

Answer (score 0):

You use getLastKnownLocation if you want the location right now.  If you're waiting for it to be non-null, you should requestLocationUpdates instead.  If that's overkill because you don't want more than 1 update, use requestSingleUpdate.

Comment: Gabe, yes I know that, that getLastKnownLocation has the potential to return null and I am requesting location updates, I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way to alert the user to the fact that there was not yet a valid location.